# How can background color be changed for checkable QPushButton descendant?

Tags: c++, qt, qpushbutton

I use C++, Qt 4.8.7, Visual Studio in order to create GUI-based application. I have to add some checkable buttons, which contain captions with subcripts. I use 3rd party buttons from github, see [richtextpushbutton.h](https://github.com/krf/kdevplatform/blob/57647e3f3703383270612a84196ac24763ce1cc3/util/richtextpushbutton.h) and [richtextpushbutton.cpp](https://github.com/krf/kdevplatform/blob/57647e3f3703383270612a84196ac24763ce1cc3/util/richtextpushbutton.cpp). The default look of the checked `QPushButton` looks awful (unreadable), I'd like to change its background in the checked state. How can I change the following methods in order to override background color of this HTML-supporting button for the checked state (when `isRichText` is true and false)? I've met only examples for simple `QPushButton` descendants (without `QTextDocument`).

```
void RichTextPushButton::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
   if (isRichText) {
    QStylePainter p(this);

    QRect buttonRect = rect();
    QPoint point;

    QTextDocument richTextLabel;
    richTextLabel.setHtml(htmlText);

    QPixmap richTextPixmap(richTextLabel.size().width(), richTextLabel.size().height());
    richTextPixmap.fill(Qt::transparent);
    QPainter richTextPainter(&richTextPixmap);
    richTextLabel.drawContents(&richTextPainter, richTextPixmap.rect());

    if (!icon().isNull())
        point = QPoint(buttonRect.x() + buttonRect.width() / 2 + iconSize().width() / 2 + 2, buttonRect.y() + buttonRect.height() / 2);
    else
        point = QPoint(buttonRect.x() + buttonRect.width() / 2 - 1, buttonRect.y() + buttonRect.height() / 2);

    buttonRect.translate(point.x() - richTextPixmap.width() / 2, point.y() - richTextPixmap.height() / 2);

    p.drawControl(QStyle::CE_PushButton, getStyleOption());
    p.drawPixmap(buttonRect.left(), buttonRect.top(), richTextPixmap.width(), richTextPixmap.height(),richTextPixmap);
} else
    QPushButton::paintEvent(event);
}

QStyleOptionButton RichTextPushButton::getStyleOption() const
{
QStyleOptionButton opt;
opt.initFrom(this);
opt.features = QStyleOptionButton::None;
if (isFlat())
    opt.features |= QStyleOptionButton::Flat;
if (menu())
    opt.features |= QStyleOptionButton::HasMenu;
if (autoDefault() || isDefault())
    opt.features |= QStyleOptionButton::AutoDefaultButton;
if (isDefault())
    opt.features |= QStyleOptionButton::DefaultButton;
if (isDown() || (menu() && menu()->isVisible()))
    opt.state |= QStyle::State_Sunken;
if (isChecked())
    opt.state |= QStyle::State_On;
if (!isFlat() && !isDown())
    opt.state |= QStyle::State_Raised;
if (!isRichText)
    opt.text = QPushButton::text();
opt.icon = icon();
opt.iconSize = iconSize();
return opt;
}
```

Comment: Why can't you simply change the background colour when the [`clicked`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked) or [`toggled`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#toggled) signals are emitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to go is to use stylesheets. As you see in `getStyleOption()` the state `QStyle::State_On` is set when the button is checked which corresponds to the `:on` pseudo state. In case of the push button the pseudo state `:checked` may apply too.

> QStyle::State_Off 0x00000008  Used to indicate if the widget is not
>   checked.
>
> QStyle::State_On  0x00000020  Used to indicate if the widget is
>   checked.

So your stylesheet could look like:

```
RichTextPushButton:checked {
    background-color: red;
}
```

If your `isRichText` variable is a dynamic property (QObject::property) you can restrict your stylesheet further:

```
RichTextPushButton[isRichText="true"]:checked {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried with your stylesheet, but the color is not solid (red is mixed with gray).

Comment: Adding `border: none;` solved it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718722/how-to-style-qpushbuttons-checked-state-to-remove-grey-dots

Answer (score 2):

> The default look of the checked QPushButton looks awful

That's why Qt introduced stylesheets many years ago. [Check this out](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-a-qpushbutton-using-the-box-model).

To change the background color of a pushed button simply do:

```
void MyClass::slotToggleButton(bool enable)
{
    m_pushButton->setStyleSheet(enable ? "background: green;" : "");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've used stylesheets, but I didn't know about possibility of the hybrid approach (mixing custom `paintEvent` and `setStyleSheet`).

Comment: But if I use HTML mode for `RichTextPushButton` (`isRichText == true` ), then font style is ignored.